# How to search for X character set item in cell divided by underscore

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the following value in a cell "test1_test2_test3_test4_test5". In another cell it could be "test1_test2_test3" or even "test 1_t est2".

What I would like is to have a 'general' function that I can specify to only give me back e.g. all characters before the first underscore, between the first en second underscore etc...and all the characters after the last underscore. And....if there isn't anything found, don't give back an error but just empty or nothing.

Thusfar I've googled a working format for when having a maximum of 2 underscores present (each different in formula):
For locating and displaying the characters before the first underscore: =LEFT(D32; SEARCH("*";D32;1)-1)
For locating the characters after the first and before the second underscore: =MID(D32;SEARCH("*";D32;1)+1;SEARCH("*";D32;SEARCH("*";D32;1)+1)-(SEARCH("*";D32;1))-1)
For locating the characters after the second underscore (not limiting untill the next one is/is not present): =RIGHT(D32;LEN(D32)-SEARCH("*";D32;SEARCH("_";D32;1)+1))

Ps: because my native (excel) language is Dutch, I've done my best to translate my working Excel functions to the English syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And when I want to have the segments vertically I just have to change 'COLUMS' into ROWS?

Comment: You would change `COLUMNS($A:A)` to `ROWS($1:1)`. This is a standard method of creating an ordinal increment (e.g. *1, 2, 3, 4, ...*) as something is filled right or down. You can also use `COLUMN(A:A)` or `ROW(1:1)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Text to Columns with underscore as the delimiter, count how many pieces result ([COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)) and then pick to suit accordingly. Use [IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) to return blank (`""`) if say you want the text after the second underscore and the count is `1`.